# MiniProfiler, get rid of request for own resources

Tags: .net, mvc-mini-profiler

What's the easiest way to get rid of profiling info about MiniProfiler's own resources, e.g `http://localhost:9591/admin/mini-profiler-resources/results`

**Setup in Application_Start**

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter());
MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42(true);
MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new SqlServerFormatter();

var viewEnginesCopy = viewEngines.ToArray();
viewEngines.Clear();
foreach (var viewEngine in viewEnginesCopy)
    viewEngines.Add(new ProfilingViewEngine(viewEngine));
```

**In _Layout before `</body>`**

```
@StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
```

Comment: odd; when I configure mini-profiler on a standard setup, I never see that...? is there anything unusual in your setup?

Comment: Updated question with configuration code.

Comment: I read about the "UseExistingjQuery" setting because that's one resource being loaded, but that doesn't seem to be in the latest NuGet, right?

Comment: I have the same problem, it only started happening once I had upgraded to MiniProfiler 2.0.1 (from 1.9)

Comment: I thought I just deployed a fix for this, can you try getting latest from nuget

Comment: That fixed it for me (I upgraded to MiniProfiler 2.0.2). Thanks @Sam !

Comment: Thanks! Put that as an answer, Sam, and I'll mark it as "Accepted". Everything for the scores ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an open bug in the 2.0.1 release, it has been fixed and deployed to nuget.